# not being able to display button in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
const element = <h1>Hello, 1234world</h1>;
root.render(element);
const root2 = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('tworoot'));
const element2 = <h1>Hello, 5678world</h1>;
root2.render(element2);

function MyButton() {
  return (
    <button>
      I'm a button
    </button>
  );
}

export default function MyApp() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to my app</h1>
      <MyButton />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h2>Add React in One Minute</h2>
    <p>This page demonstrates using React with no build tooling.</p>
    <p>React is loaded as a script tag.</p>

    <!-- We will put our React component inside this div. -->
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="tworoot"></div>

    <!-- Load React. -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

    <!-- Load your React component. -->
    <script src="lik.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Upon rendering my html page,I am getting console log error as Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' and my Button is not being displayed.[button](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn).please advise me as I think I am nt getting the concepts right

Comment: You need to add `type="module"` but it still won't work, because you need babel to transform jsx into js

Comment: I preproccessed JSX by running the command.. npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod command

Comment: this is my localhost server running using command python -m http.server 3000 , will this be an issue?

Comment: Doesn't `<script type="module" src="lik.js"></script>` fix the issue?

Comment: it fixed the error message but the button is not being displayed

Comment: Where are you using MyApp? I don't see it appended anywhere.

Comment: as per the official doc https://beta.reactjs.org/learn , I cant see where to append

Comment: Change this line `const element2 = <h1>Hello, 5678world</h1>;` to this `const element2 = <MyApp />;` and see if that works?

Comment: worked, please post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to render the Button, you have to render the component referencing it, in this case, MyApp.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
const element = <h1>Hello, 1234world</h1>;
root.render(element);
const root2 = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('tworoot'));
const element2 = <MyApp />;
root2.render(element2);
```

Comment: As an aside, you can also just render the button, without MyApp, if you wanted to, but I didn't want to change what you had, structurally, in case your exports change.